# How can we add a child tag if another childtag has specific string in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML contains the following lines. I want to add a child tag <PV1.2>IN</PV1.2> if the <PV1.18> has the value "INR".

```
<PV1>
  <PV1.1>0001</PV1.1>
  <PV1.3>
    <PL.1>5N</PL.1>
    <PL.2>0552</PL.2>
    <PL.3>0B</PL.3>
  </PV1.3>
  <PV1.8>INR</PV1.8>
  <PV1.19>
    <CX.1>000002194171</CX.1>
  </PV1.19>
</PV1>
```

Output shoud be:

```
<PV1>
  <PV1.1>0001</PV1.1>
  <PV1.2>IN</PV1.2>
  <PV1.3>
    <PL.1>5N</PL.1>
    <PL.2>0552</PL.2>
    <PL.3>0B</PL.3>
  </PV1.3>
  <PV1.8>INR</PV1.8>
  <PV1.19>
    <CX.1>000002194171</CX.1>
  </PV1.19>
</PV1>
```

The piece of code I tried in XSLT is as below; but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match="PV1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="PV1.18 eq 'INR'">
      <PV1.2>IN</PV1.2>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In future, please indent your XML correctly.  Also, please specify what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: @Jim, I meant to say it did not add <PV1.2>IN</PV1.2>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the xslt template you have provided, not only will it not add the **PV1.2** element, it should output nothing at all because it there is any code to copy across all the existing elements.

Anyway, this may be a typo, but your current template is looking for **PV1.18**, when there is none in your XML. I think perhaps **PV1.8** should be **PV1.18** in your XML sample. (I also think you should be using '=' and not 'eq' here). Ideally though, this should check should not be in an **xsl:choose** (especially when you don't have an **xsl:otherwise**), but you should do the check in a template match

```
<xsl:template match="PV1[PV1.18 = 'INR']">
```

Then within the template you would have to copy the existing **PVI1** element, create the **PV1.2** element, and also output the children.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="PV1[PV1.18 = 'INR']">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="PV1.1"/>
         <PV1.2>IN</PV1.2>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::PV1.1)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main thing to note here is the use of the Identity Transform, which will copy across all the other elements as-is, so you only need templates for things you need to transform. There are two **xsl:apply-templates** here, because it looks like you won't to insert the **PV1.2** after **PV1.1**.

In the case of a **PV1** element having no PV1.18 = 'INR', then the identity template does all the work, and the output will be the same as the input.